# How to include external libraries inside my project

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, driver

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to create KMDF drivers for Windows 10. While looking into this I saw multiple projects use something called [DMF](https://github.com/microsoft/DMF). Those other projects [example](https://github.com/ViGEm/ViGEmBus) would state the following for how to use this external library.

```
Step 3: Clone the Driver Module Framework (DMF) into the same parent directory.
Build the DmfK project with Release and Debug configurations for all architectures (x64 and Win32).
```

Now I am not exactly sure why it needs to be in the same parent directory (assuming of my KMDF driver). But I cloned it to the same directory and then built it 4 times for all architectures. Now inside the code of that `example` I linked to above I noticed the only `#include` statement relating to "Dmf" was `#include <DmfModules.Library.h>` which is where my question stems from because how does this work? With my limited experience with linking to DLL and LIB files I did the following to gain access to the api of DMF.

```
* 1.0 Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additonal Include Directories -> then add C:\Users\me\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Dmf\Framework
* 1.1 Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additonal Include Directories -> then add C:\Users\me\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Dmf\Modules.Library
* 1.2 Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additonal Include Directories -> then add C:\Users\me\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Dmf\Modules.Library.Tests
* 1.3 Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additonal Include Directories -> then add C:\Users\me\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Dmf\Modules.Template

* 2. Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additonal Library Directories -> then add C:\Users\me\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Release\x64\lib\DmfK

* 3. Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additonal Dependencies -> DmfK.lib
```

Now I am sure I don't need to include all of those from C/C++ -> General but I was just making sure I covered my bases. Anyways I was then able to directly include headers I wanted for example
`#include "DmfDefinitions.h"` and `#include "Dmf_BufferQueue.h"` which did seem to work. However, issues arise when I try to build my previously working driver where I would receive 200+ errors all originating inside of random header files along with Dmf specific headers. For example here are some of the many errors I recieved.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1389   redeclaration cannot add dllexport/dllimport to "WdmlibRtlInitUnicodeStringEx" (declared at line 417 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\wdmsec.h")  KMDF    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\ntifs.h  2417    
Error   C2371   'PEPROCESS': redefinition; different basic types    KMDF    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\ntifs.h  85  
Error   C2371   'PETHREAD': redefinition; different basic types KMDF    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\ntifs.h  86  
Error   C2375   'WdmlibRtlInitUnicodeStringEx': redefinition; different linkage KMDF    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km\ntifs.h  2417    
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'BufferPool_SourceSettings'    KMDF    C:\Users\me\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Dmf\Modules.Library\Dmf_BufferQueue.h 43  
Error   C2059   syntax error: '}'   KMDF    C:\Users\me\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Dmf\Modules.Library\Dmf_BufferQueue.h 47  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before '*'    KMDF    C:\Users\me\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Dmf\Modules.Library\Dmf_BufferQueue.h 56  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing '{' before '*'    KMDF    C:\Users\me\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Dmf\Modules.Library\Dmf_BufferQueue.h 56  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   KMDF    C:\Users\ME\source\repos\KMDF\DMF\Dmf\Modules.Library\Dmf_BufferQueue.h 57
```

---

Please note this is only an issue when I try to use any API from Dmf and none of my C files or headers have any errors or warnings. I assume this is because my method for including Dmf is wrong since the examples include statement was just `<DmfModules.Library.h>` but I have no idea how to do this in order to correctly build my driver with Dmf.